# How to change the alpha value of the first table in grouped table in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alpha, grouped-table

I am new to iphone development. I am displaying my content in grouped table view. I want to change the alpha value of the first group of my table only. How can i achieve that. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "first table"?

Changing the alpha value of a table is done by

```
table.alpha = new_value
```

where new_value ranges from 0 to 1.

Marco

Comment: He has a grouped table view.
He's trying to get the first group to change it's alpha value.

Comment: would making the table non opaque and then changing the cells of the first group work?